# Truncate string to show "read more" after a certain number of characters?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the class "news-body" only show a maximum amount of characters(for example 300 characters). After the max has been reached I want the text to stop and I want to display "read more."

Any help is appreciated.

```
  var news={};

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      dataType:"json",
      url:"articles.json",
      success: function (data){
       news = data;

            for (var i = 0; i < news.articles.length; i++) {

            var row = $ ('<div>');
            row.addClass('row');

            var container = $ ('<div>');
            container.addClass('col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news');

            var newsTitle = $ ('<p>');
            newsTitle.addClass('news-title');
            newsTitle.text(news.articles[i].name);
            container.append(newsTitle);

            var newsImg = $ ('<img>');
            newsImg.addClass('news-img');
            newsImg.attr("src", news.articles[i].img);
            container.append(newsImg);

            var newsTime = $ ('<p>');
            newsTime.addClass('news-time');
            newsTime.text(news.articles[i].date);
            container.append(newsTime);

            var newsBody = $ ('<p>');
            newsBody.addClass('news-body');
            newsBody.text(news.articles[i].deats);
            container.append(newsBody);

            $("#news").append(container);
          }

    },
     error:function(e){console.log(e)}
    })
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `slice()` your `news.articles[i].deats` string at the number of characters you want to show:

```
newsBody.text(news.articles[i].deats.slice(0,300));
```

And then append a link to wherever you're sticking the rest of the article, or put the rest of the article in a hidden div that shows on click. Lots of options for that part depending on how your site is laid out.

Comment: Like I said, there's a couple ways to do it. If you want clicking "read more" to display the rest of the article on the same page, you could add a click handler that displays a hidden div containing  `newsBody.text(news.articles[i].deats.slice(300));` but that's really a separate question